# Convert Func<T1,bool> to Func<T2,bool> in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

How can I convert `Func<DepartmentViewModel, bool>` to
`Func<Department, bool>`?

I have seen a lot of posts about this problem but none of those could help me.

I call this function :

```
public DepartmentViewModel GetSingle(Expression<Func<DepartmentViewModel, bool>> whereCondition)
```

from GUI layer like this :

```
_departmentService.GetSingle(de => de.Id ==id));
```

and inside `GetSingle` function which locate in my business layer I must call

```
public IEnumerable<Department> GetAll(Func<Department, bool> predicate = null)
```

but `GetAll` function accepts a `Func<Department, bool>` type

This is my object :

```
class Department {
   public string name
}
```

and

```
class DepartmentViewModel{
   public string name
}
```

---

regard , I found best answer :
 `Func<DepartmentViewModel, bool> some_function = whereCondition.Compile();`
 `Func<Department, bool> converted = d => some_function(
                new DepartmentViewModel {
                    Id=d.Id,
                    Description=d.Descriptions
                }
                );`

Comment: Could you give a concrete example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want pass "DTO where condition" from business layer to access layer`public DepartmentViewModel GetSingle(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<DepartmentViewModel, bool>> whereCondition)` to `public IEnumerable< Department> GetAll(Func< Department, bool> predicate = null)`

Comment: How do you convert from `Department` to `DepartmentViewModel`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change `Func<T1,bool>` to `Func<T2,bool>`, but you can convert expression of the same.

That requires a bit of work, First you have to pass `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`, then you can easily convert your expression to match incoming parameter.

So you can change your method to,

```
Expression<Func<DepartmentViewModel,bool>> srcLambda = 
     x => x.DepartmentName.StartsWith("Admin")

Expression<Func<Department,bool>> destLambda = 
     ConvertTo<Department,DepartmentViewModel>( srcLambda);
```

This assumes that DepartmentViewModel (DTO) has same fields as Department. Otherwise, you will have to change the code a bit to fit your needs.

```
public static Expression<Func<TDest,bool>> 
      ConvertTo<TSrc,TDest>(Expression<Func<TSrc,bool>> srcExp)
{
    ParameterExpression destPE = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDest));

    ExpressionConverter ec = new ExpressionConverter(typeof(TSrc),destPE);
    Expression body = ec.Visit(srcExp.Body);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TDest,bool>>(body,destPE);
} 

public class ExpressionConverter: ExpressionVisitor{

    private Type srcType;
    private ParameterExpression destParameter;

    public ExpressionConverter(Type src, ParameterExpression dest){
        this.srcType = src;
        this.destParameter= dest;
    } 

    protected override Expression 
       VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        if(node.Type == srcType)
            return this.destParameter;
        return base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is tc in line `Expression body = tc.Visit(srcExp.Body);`

Comment: @Farazjalili It just looks like a typo for `ec` to me.

Comment: @Farazjalili it was just typo

Comment: regard , amazing after run above code show Server Error page and say Property 'Int32 Id' is not defined for type Department '

Comment: @Farazjalili, does DepartmentViewModel have Department as property? read my comments, the code should change based on how properties are declared.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to issue these queries to Entity Framework (or some other query provider). In that case, you need to work with expressions, not just functions, since only the former store the query information required to be transformed by the provider (for example, into SQL queries).

Here's a simple example:

```
Expression<Func<DepartmentViewModel, bool>> filterDVM = dvm => dvm.Name == "abc";
```

You first need to have some logic that will accept a `Department` and convert it into a `DepartmentViewModel`:

```
Expression<Func<Department, DepartmentViewModel>> getViewModel = dep => 
    new DepartmentViewModel
    {
        Name = dep.Name,
        Location = dep.Location,
    };
```

Once you have this, you can apply your transformation onto the `IQueryable<Department>` sequence, after which, you can apply your filter:

```
var dvm = context.Departments.Select(getViewModel).Where(filterDVM);
```

Comment: tnx for answer can you adept your answer with my condition, this function related my business layer public DepartmentViewModel GetSingle(Expression<Func<DepartmentViewModel, bool>> whereCondition) and I want pass where whereCondition to Access layer which have signature like this public IEnumerable< Department> GetAll(Func< Department, bool> predicate = null) , DepartmentViewModel  and Department object have similar property

Comment: unfortunately I haven't direct access to EF provider I can only call function public IEnumerable< Department> GetAll(Func< Department, bool> predicate = null) which locate in DataAccessLayer I need just where and how do convert Func<DepartmentsViewmodel,bool> to Func<Departments,bool>

Comment: @Farazjalili: Could you rework all the additional information coherently into your original question? It's hard to read what you're trying to achieve from the comments.